# Drop items with all NaN values from a pandas multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some trouble wrangling a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
                    value
year        name
2015        bob     10.0
            cat     NaN
2016        bob     NaN
            cat     NaN
```

I want to drop those items where all the `value`s for the same `name` are NaN. In this case the result should be this:

```
                    value
year        name
2015        bob     10.0
2016        bob     NaN
```

All the `cat` values were NaN so `cat` is gone. Since `bob` had one non-NaN value, it gets to stay.

Note that both the `2016` values were NaN in the input, but `2016` is still around in the output - because this rule only applies to the `name` column. Ideally I'd like to be able to provide which column this applies to as a parameter.

Is this even possible? How should I do this? I'm okay with reindexing/transposing/whatever if that's needed to get the job done (only if it's necessary though!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby` with `filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration)

```
df.groupby(level='name').filter(lambda x: x.value.notnull().any())

           value
year name       
2015 bob    10.0
2016 bob     NaN
```

Comment: I get an `{AttributeError}'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'` when I use this on my actual dataframe. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @spinningarrow value is the column name. Change it to whatever your column name is

Comment: makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [208]: df.reset_index().sort_values('name').drop_duplicates(['value']).set_index(['year','name'])
Out[208]:
           value
year name
2015 bob    10.0
2016 bob     NaN
```

Comment: Will `drop_duplicates` have unintended effects? e.g. if the value for both `cat`s was `100` instead of NaN, it would still get removed right? I only want NaN values to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unstack`, `isnull`, `all`, and `stack`:

```
df.unstack().loc[:,~df.unstack().isnull().all()].stack(-1, dropna=False)
```

Or use `notnull` and `any`:

```
df.unstack().loc[:,df.unstack().notnull().any()].stack(-1, dropna=False)
```

Output:

```
              value
year name       
2015 bob    10.0
2016 bob     NaN
```